# How can we transform Date in CSV file using PowerShell scripts

Tags: powershell

I have a csv file having a column - Date. Currently its format is 7/30/2019.
I want to make Date transformations using PowerShell. The required format would be: 2019-30-07. How can we do that?

I used following code to do this. But it is only doing partial for some records only. And not for other records.

Code I am using:

```
(get-content FileCheck.csv) -replace "(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})", '$3-$2-$1'  |
    sc Output3.csv
```

Comment: load the file via `Import-CSV`, iterate thru that collection of objects & convert the date STRING to a date _object_ ... and then use the `.ToString()` method of that object to make a new date string in the format you prefer. [*grin*] then, finally, save to a new CSV file with `Export-CSV`.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to cast as `[DateTime]` and then output in the format you want. Example:

```
Import-Csv ImportData.csv | Select-Object LastName,FirstName,
  @{Name = "Date"; Expression = {"{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" -f ($_.Date -as [DateTime])}}
} | Export-Csv New.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This example selects the columns and uses a calculated property to cast the date to the `[DateTime]` type and then output in the desired string format.

Comment: Tried it. But it is exporting the date with blank column.

Comment: Update your question with a sample row from your input file. (Don't forget to include the header row with the column names.)

Answer (score 0):

To have less trouble modifying a csv file,
without knowing or altering the order of columns,
you can user the following script.

- It 1st reads in the original header
- after replacing the `Date` column with the reformatted one with a calculated property
  (which would otherwise be the last column)
- it reestablishes the previous order with an additional `Select-Object`

---

```
## Q:\Test\2019\06\10\SO_56528528.ps1

$CsvIN  = '.\Sample.csv'
$CsvOut = '.\NewSample.csv'
$Header = (Get-Content $CsvIn -Head 1).split(',')

Import-Csv $CsvIn |
  Select-Object *,@{n='Date';e={(Get-Date $_.Date).ToString('yyyy\-MM\-dd')}} -ExcludeProperty Date | 
    Select-Object $Header | 
      Export-Csv $CsvOut -NoTypeInformation
```

---

```
> Get-Content .\Sample.csv
foo,bar,Date,baz
abc,def,7/30/2019,ghi
```

---

```
> Get-Content .\NewSample.csv
"foo","bar","Date","baz"
"abc","def","2019-07-30","ghi"
```